# Not able to access the internet on CentOS 6.2?

Tags: centos

I have installed the VMware Player to use the CentOS 6.2 on my machine having Windows XP operating system. When I am using the CentOS , I am not able to access the internet . But the sites hosted by our organization's intranet are accessible.

Also , I am able to access the internet and intranet  when I am accessing it in the XP environment.

I have not created any user for the CentOS and it is avaialbe to me  when I am selecting any instance of the CentOS through the VMware Player.

Looking for Help!

Comment: Try to set it using bridge network and ensure your DHCP server will give a separate IP for the CentOS (of course, you need to configure your CentOS to obtain IP from network).  The vmnet8 not doing a very stable job at all.

Comment: thanks @Ken Cheung ! Could you please guide me , I am very new to this field . And if you can provide me any link or the required steps to solve this  issue , then I will be grateful to you!

Comment: Launch VMware Player, right click on your VM, select "Virtual Machine Settings", under "Hardware" tab, choose "Network Adapter" and ensure it selects "Bridged". Inside CentOS, if you have GUI go to Network Manager to configure the network, otherwise modify /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

Comment: okay. Thanks a lot Ken Cheung for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and it seems the solution is to modify

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

So that the line reads
 `ONBOOT=yes` instead of the default   `ONBOOT=no`

Then restart your computer, or run `ifup eth0` and you should have internet working. Since the default is to have no network, it can be tricky to find the solution if you haven't got another computer to look it up from!

Comment: This helped me to get my internet working on a CentOS7 minimal install, although in my case I needed to do 2 things: 

(1) edit resolv.conf to add DNS entries 
(2) edit ifcfg-ens33 to set ONBOOT=yes